# Partition by Week - Oracle Database

Tags: sql, oracle, database-partitioning

I was wondering if you can help me figure out and deal with partitioning by week in Oracle.

My Situation is that I have a lot of data which is coming per day and I would like to make partitions per week. I will be also using sysdate when inserting the data to the DB in order to make the record unique.

Should I write them manually? If yes, how should it look? Should I still use something like: VALUES LESS THAN?

Really looking forward to hearing your opinions!

Comment: You can use range partitioning like `PARTITION BY RANGE (DATE_COLUMN)
INTERVAL ( INTERVAL '7' DAY)
`

Comment: http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_interval_partitioning.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Weekly partition is a problem but you can create interval partition for 7 days. Oracle will automatically create new partition for new entries.

```
create table TEST_partition
(
  ID              number(4, 0)
, creation_date   date
)
partition by range  (creation_date)
  interval ( numtodsinterval(7, 'day') )
  (partition TEST_P1 values less than (to_date(' 2018-01-01 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN')));
```

Comment: Why are weekly partitions a problem?

Comment: @VBABegginer - Possibly he means due to trying to "force" the first day of the week?  But by expressly creating an partition for "less than 1st Jan 2018", the next partition will be from 1st Jan 2018, so he has successfully "forced" the week to start from a Monday?

Comment: PARTITION BY RANGE ("WEEK")
   (PARTITION "P2" VALUES LESS THAN (40), 
    PARTITION "P3" VALUES LESS THAN (42)); is something like this going to work ? @MatBailie

Comment: @VBABegginer - That doesn't have an INTERVAL clause, so it won't grow automatically.  I suggest starting from the code given in this answer, and reading the link I gave in my comment to the OP.

Comment: @MatBailie, I just finished checking both the answer and the article and adapted them to my situation and it works. However i just wanted to make it clear for myself. Also is it possible to predefined all partitions? For all the weeks in a year, because as you said they will not grow automatically, but if I predefine them, will it work? Thank you Arkadiusz for the help, I will mark it as answered.

Comment: @VBABegginer - If you have a "Week" column with values from 1 to 52, you'll find some years have a week 53 so make sure there is space for that too.  Week 1 from 2017 and Week 1 form 2018 will be in the same Partition, is that what you want?  If you're happy with such behaviours, your approach is fine.  But don't believe Anything that Anyone tells you on the internet, create some tests with test data that covers the cases that you want to prove.  *(Unit Testing.........)*

Comment: Week is very problematic case. Oracle support two way to supporting week.
1-st  `WW`- Week of year (1-53) where week 1 starts on the first day of the year and continues to the seventh day of the year. ,2-nd `IW` Week of year (1-52 or 1-53) based on the ISO standard.
`select trunc(to_date('2010-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd'),'IW'),trunc(to_date('2010-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd'),'WW')  from dual` - here is real example with difference. And iso definition https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date#First_week

Comment: @VBABegginer - it will only "not grow automatically" if you remove the `interval` clause used in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create interval partition as follows:

```sql
CREATE TABLE invoices
(invoice_no    NUMBER NOT NULL,
 invoice_date  DATE   NOT NULL,
 comments      VARCHAR2(500))
PARTITION BY RANGE (invoice_date)
INTERVAL (NUMTODSINTERVAL(7,'DAY'))
(PARTITION invoices_q1 VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('01/04/2001', 'DD/MM/YYYY')));
```

It creates a new partition for 7 days starting from Sunday to Saturday.